# How to record a Script By using JMeter

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

when i change the proxy settings the Save button is not getting enable, can anyone help  me to to record the script by for Android Application.

please share Videos to Record a script for android.

Thanks In Adavance.

Comment: See this: https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207420545-BlazeMeter-Proxy-Recorder-Mobile-and-web-

Comment: Hi, Sir I need Script Record Video To do the load Test By Using JMeter.

Comment: Yes, Did you follow the link provided? There are also videos for recording a script.You can easily export the recorded script as a JMeter file (.jmx) and run the load test in JMeter.

Comment: Yes,sir i followed but don't no how to Configure with mobile.

Comment: Hi, sir But actually need to do record Script By using J Meter.

Comment: Then follow the provided answer given by Dmitri. Thanks!

Comment: Actually the link i got for Blazemeter.. i need the clarification J meter how to record a script by using Jmeter Script Record.

Comment: How can i change the Proxy Settings . To Record the script for Android Application By using J meter. Thanks In Advance

Comment: Go to the wifi connection from your device and then tap and hold to modify your network. You can add the proxy settings there.

Comment: How can i configure my mobile with J meter. Because I m performing load Test for Android Application. is there any configuration needed to connect with mobile. How can i configure My mobile with J meter

Comment: How can i configure my mobile with J meter. Because I m performing load Test for Android Application. is there any configuration needed to connect with mobile. How can i configure My mobile with J meter ?

Comment: Already replied a couple of times!! You can easily follow the  4 steps provided by Dmitri's answer which is using JMeter for recording. Let me know, what have you tried so far? Edit or update your question with your steps. Thank you!

Comment: i cant able to configure my mobile with j meter

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure your Android device is connected to the same network as the machine running JMeter
2. Prepare JMeter for recording, the fastest and the easiest way is using [templates feature](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#template), from JMeter's main menu choose `File -> Templates -> Recording -> Create`
3. Expand Workbench -> [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) and click "Start"
4. Configure your mobile device to use JMeter as a proxy, use IP address or hostname of machine where JMeter is running as proxy host and `8888` as proxy port

If application you're trying to record is using HTTPS transport you will need to import JMeter's self-signed certificate onto the device. Locate `ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt` file (it is being generated in JMeter's "bin" folder when you start HTTP(S) Test Script recorder) and send it to yourself via the email. Once done - open the attachment on the Android device and follow installation dialog. You may also need a 3rd-party tool like [ProxyDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.proxydroid) in order to configure HTTPS proxy.

See [Load Testing Mobile Apps Made Easy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/load-testing-mobile-apps-made-easy) guide for comprehensive instructions.